# How to force Apache Tapestry update javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, caching, tapestry

After changes of javascript (or in separate file or as part of page) browser doesn't refresh it.
Could it be done by Apache Tapestry?
The first solution it is look like generating script hash and putting during assembly javascript files into the directory with name that includes hash.
But it is not clear how to refresh javascript that is included into .html page?
Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0):

When Tapestry (5.3 and later) is running in production mode, which is the default, page reloading is disabled.

Try disabling production mode as described in the [Tapestry docs](https://tapestry.apache.org/class-reloading.html#ClassReloading-IfLiveClassReloadingdoesn'twork).